# see if list of keys exist in dictionaries of a dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list:

```
allDatetimes = ['6/1/2014 0:10', '6/1/2014 0:20', '6/1/2014 0:15']
```

and a dictionary:

```
dtDict={'AV-IM-1-13991730': {'6/1/2014 0:10': '0.96', '6/1/2014 0:20': '0.97', '6/1/2014 0:15': '0.92'}, 'AV-IM-1-13991731': {'6/1/2014 0:10': '1.96', '6/1/2014 0:20': '1.97', '6/1/2014 0:15': '1.92'}, 'AV-IM-1-13991732': {'6/1/2014 0:10': '2.96', '6/1/2014 0:20': '2.97', '6/1/2014 0:15': '2.92'}, 'AV-IM-1-13991733': {'6/1/2014 0:20': '3.97', '6/1/2014 0:10': '3.96'}}
```

What am I trying to do?

Compare `allDatetimes` to the keys of each dictionary in `dtDates` dictionary and if a key doesn't exist, I want to add it and give it a value of previous key. For example, in the above `dtDates` dictionary, for key `AV-IM-1-13991733`, we can see that `6/1/2014 0:15` is missing, so I want to add that key and give it a value equal to the value of previous key, so I want to change  `dtDict` to:

```
dtDict={'AV-IM-1-13991730': {'6/1/2014 0:10': '0.96', '6/1/2014 0:20': '0.97', '6/1/2014 0:15': '0.92'}, 'AV-IM-1-13991731': {'6/1/2014 0:10': '1.96', '6/1/2014 0:20': '1.97', '6/1/2014 0:15': '1.92'}, 'AV-IM-1-13991732': {'6/1/2014 0:10': '2.96', '6/1/2014 0:20': '2.97', '6/1/2014 0:15': '2.92'}, 'AV-IM-1-13991733': {'6/1/2014 0:20': '3.97', '6/1/2014 0:10': '3.96', '6/1/2014 0:15': '3.96'}}`
```

so now all the dictionaries in `dtDict` has same number of `key:value` pairs. 
In addition to the code I have right now to generate `dtDict` and `allDatetimes`, I tried this way to check the existence of the keys but it is not working:

```
for meter,date in dtDict.iteritems():
    if all(dateval in dtDict[meter] for dateval in allDatetimes):
        print meter,dateval,volt
        #then how do I "add" the missing key and give it a value of previous key?
```

Comment: dicts have no order so what is the previous key?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham the best value would be the previous time-stamp value. second option (if there is no way to get the previous timestamp value) is just the value of previous key.

Comment: Do you mean the last whatever key happened to come along while iterating key?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham i want to grab the value of previous timestamp. for example: if **6/1/2014 0:20** key is missing, i want to **6/1/2014 0:20** and the value of **6/1/2014 0:15**, so the new key-value pair would be: `'6/1/2014 0:20': '0.92'`

Comment: So by previous you mean the previous timestamp?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yea

Comment: Try the answer below. The second part should be what you want but as I say in the answer the earliest timestamp will not have a previous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok if I understand you correctly, something like this?:

```
allDatetimes = {'6/1/2014 0:10', '6/1/2014 0:20', '6/1/2014 0:15'}

dtDict = {'AV-IM-1-13991730': {'6/1/2014 0:10': '0.96', '6/1/2014 0:20': '0.97', '6/1/2014 0:15': '0.92'}, 'AV-IM-1-13991731': {'6/1/2014 0:10': '1.96', '6/1/2014 0:20': '1.97', '6/1/2014 0:15': '1.92'}, 'AV-IM-1-13991732': {'6/1/2014 0:10': '2.96', '6/1/2014 0:20': '2.97', '6/1/2014 0:15': '2.92'}, 'AV-IM-1-13991733': {'6/1/2014 0:20': '3.97', '6/1/2014 0:10': '3.96'}}
from datetime import datetime
for k,d in dtDict.iteritems(): # .items python3
    diff = allDatetimes - d.viewkeys() # .keys() python3
    for k in diff:
        dt1 = datetime.strptime(k, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M" )
        d[k] = d[min(d,key=lambda x: abs(dt1 - datetime.strptime(x,"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")))]
from pprint import  pprint as pp
pp(dtDict)
```

Output:

```
{'AV-IM-1-13991730': {'6/1/2014 0:10': '0.96',
                      '6/1/2014 0:15': '0.92',
                      '6/1/2014 0:20': '0.97'},
 'AV-IM-1-13991731': {'6/1/2014 0:10': '1.96',
                      '6/1/2014 0:15': '1.92',
                      '6/1/2014 0:20': '1.97'},
 'AV-IM-1-13991732': {'6/1/2014 0:10': '2.96',
                      '6/1/2014 0:15': '2.92',
                      '6/1/2014 0:20': '2.97'},
 'AV-IM-1-13991733': {'6/1/2014 0:10': '3.96',
                      '6/1/2014 0:15': '3.96',
                      '6/1/2014 0:20': '3.97'}}
```

`diff = allDatetimes - d.viewkeys()` finds the keys that are not in `allDatetimes` which I made a set, we then find the closest timestamp and set that keys value as the value for the missing key.

The only bug is the code will also find the closest timestamp that is after the timestamp itself, we can roll a function that will make sure we only find times that are before our timestamp but bear in mind if you have the earliest timestamp as the missing key there will be no earlier time, what you do then is something you will have to decide:

```
def find_closest(dt,x):
    dt2 = datetime.strptime(x,"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
    return abs(dt2 - dt) if dt > dt2 else dt2 - datetime.today()

for k,d in dtDict.items():
    diff = allDatetimes - d.viewkeys()
    for k in diff:
        dt1 = datetime.strptime(k, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M" )
        d[k] = d[min(d, key=lambda x:find_closest(dt1,x))]
```

As far as doing this efficiently I would recommend storing the keys as actual datetime objects if you are going to be doing this a lot and using an `OrderedDict` keeping the timestamps in order. It is simply a matter of using a `bisect` search or iterating in using an explicit loop to find the to find the previous timestamp/key.

Comment: allDatetimes should be [ ] instead of { } since it is a list

also, if the very first timestamp is missing I want to populate it with "nexttime stamp" value. Is it possible to add that to this code?

Comment: also, addressing your last line in the answer, how can this code be changed to have an "ordered dictionary"?

Comment: @NikhilGupta, it should take the next timestamp as is when the timestamp is the lowest,  use a collections.OrderedDict to create your dicts, adding the keys in sorted order  https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

Comment: Also we are using a set so the braces are necessary

Comment: I used the above code snippet with **allDatetimes** defined as a list and it worked.

Comment: Yes but creating a set should be more efficient